# Composer override dependency with another from packagist?

Tags: dependencies, composer-php, packagist

Good Afternoon!

I have a project which contained a mix of git submodules and composer packages.  I've converted them all over to composer for reasons.

Currently, the project uses [crisu83/yiistrap (v1.3.0)](https://packagist.org/packages/crisu83/yiistrap#1.3.0) and [2amigos/yiiwheels (v1.0.6)](https://packagist.org/packages/2amigos/yiiwheels#1.0.6).  It has used these packages for a year, maybe year and a half (as a git submodule); I know they're stable and all the bugs have been worked out.

The problem is, 2amigos/yiiwheels (v1.0.6) wants to install [2amigos/yiistrap (v1.3.0)](https://packagist.org/packages/2amigos/yiistrap#1.3.0) as a dependency.

How would I get composer to ignore the 2amigos dependency? Or ensure it the dependency is already met?  I'd prefer not to have to create my own fork.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the dependency of a package is not supported.

You can only ignore platform requirements: `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`.

Suggestion:

- do a `composer install`
- delete `vendor/2amigos/yiistrap` after running Composer,
- followed by `composer dump-autoload -o` to recreate the autoloader